# firefox extension that adds a script to a html page

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, scripting, firefox-addon

I am asking about using javascript to add a script to a html tab in firefox. I'd like to avoid using greasemonkey. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why you'd like to avoid a tool that is developed for this exact purpose. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: You want to do exactly what Greasemonkey does, but you don't want to use Greasemonkey?  Why?

Comment: I need to add it in a firefox extension, i dont know if its possible using greasemonkey :/

Comment: Yes, Lily, but *why*? It sound exactly what someone who develops a malicious piece of software would ask.

Comment: No nothing of the sort. I'm trying to use google search api in a firefox extension...and well the google.load() does not work simply from a js file...i was wondering if creating a script might

Answer (score 2):

You can use GreaseMonkey and then use the [GreaseMonkey Compiler](http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler) to turn the script into extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a bookmarklet for development purposes. Something like http://[www.learningjquery.com/2008/06/updated-jquery-bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/06/updated-jquery-bookmarklet), although a Google search will bring up many other good ones. (ps. Why does stackoverflow hilight new stuff in orange, I thinik I like yellow (light) better.)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know if this is the OP's intent, there are certain things (e.g., writing to disk) that it's not possible to do in GreaseMonkey.

(There is, or was, when I did it three years a ago, a trivial change to GM that gets around these restrictions.)

Comment: I'm trying to use the google search api to search for some terms and return a list of related sites :/

Comment: Unless you need to save that list to disk, I suspect GM will work fine for you, then.